# Flexbox align-content spacebetween not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

So what i'm trying to do is to have 3 div vertically aligned as 1st at the top, 2nd in the middle, 3rd at the bottom.

My HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-content-spacebetween" style="height:100%;">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

why isn't this working? they aligned at the top one below the other.

Comment: So i think you are using bootstrap 4..?! I think the classes are justify-content-between or align-items-center. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @GabbrIssimo thanks the "justify-content-between" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share your css code, it's hard to tell, but here's an example using flex

```css
.align-content-spacebetween{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

.align-content-spacebetween div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="align-content-spacebetween">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```